# Google Maps Places Autocomplete - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPlace' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, maps, google-places-api, angular-google-maps

```js
setAutocomplete() {
    this.originPlaceId = null;
    this.destinationPlaceId = null;
    this.travelMode = google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING;
    this.directionsDisplay.setMap(this.map);

    this.setMapControls(this.map);

    this.setupClickListener('changemode-walking', google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING);
    this.setupClickListener('changemode-transit', google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT);
    this.setupClickListener('changemode-driving', google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING);

    console.log(this.originInput);
    this.originAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.originInput);
    this.originAutocomplete.bindTo('bounds', this.map);
    console.log(this.originAutocomplete);
    this.originAutocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
        console.log(this.originAutocomplete);
        var place = this.originAutocomplete.getPlace();
        console.log("here", place);
        if (!place.geometry) {
            window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
            return;
        }
        this.expandViewportToFitPlace(this.map, place);

        // If the place has a geometry, store its place ID and route if we have
        // the other place ID
        this.originPlaceId = place.place_id;
        this.route(this.directionsService, this.directionsDisplay);
    });

    this.destinationAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.destinationPlaceInput);
    this.destinationAutocomplete.bindTo('bounds',this.map);
    this.destinationAutocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
        var place = this.destinationAutocomplete.getPlace();
        if (!place.geometry) {
            window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
            return;
        }
        this.expandViewportToFitPlace(this.map, place);

        // If the place has a geometry, store its place ID and route if we have
        // the other place ID
        this.destinationPlaceId = place.place_id;
        this.route(this.directionsService, this.directionsDisplay);
        //this.getNearbyPlaces(this.destinationPlaceId, 5000);
    });
};
```

```js
setMapControls(map) {
    this.originInput = document.getElementById('origin-input');
    this.destinationPlaceInput = document.getElementById('destination-input');
    this.modes = document.getElementById('mode-selector');

    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(this.originInput);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(this.destinationPlaceInput);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(this.modes);
};
```

```html
<input id="origin-input" class="controls" type="text" force-selection="true" placeholder="Enter an origin location">
<input id="destination-input" class="controls" type="text" force-selection="true" placeholder="Enter a destination location">
<div id="mode-selector" class="controls">
    <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-walking" checked="checked">
    <label for="changemode-walking">Walking</label>
    <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-transit">
    <label for="changemode-transit">Transit</label>
    <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-driving">
    <label for="changemode-driving">Driving</label>
</div>
<div id="directionsList"></div>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

I have these functions which are supposed to give me the directions A to B from Google Maps Places from the input fields (originInput and destinationPlaceInput).

After I select an input I have this error in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPlace' of undefined

This error is thrown after the "place_changed" event triggers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside the `place_changed`-callback the keyword `this` points to the object which has been triggered the event.

so you may simply use

```
var place = this.getPlace();
```

instead of

```
var place = this.destinationAutocomplete.getPlace();
```

Comment: Thank you. Logic 101. Guess I'm kinda tired.

Answer (score 0):

### How to keep the context/`this` of the controller?

**tldr:**

Create a function that returns a function with the context:

```
this.searchBox.addListener('places_changed', ((that) => () => this.placesChanged(that))(this));
```

---

**Explanation**

Like Dr.Molle points out: `this` points to the object which has triggered the event, namely the element on which you want to add an event listener on.

The addListener takes a function declaration. To keep access on your controller's `this`, you could also create a closure that passes the controller's `this` into the function, like so:

```
this.searchBox.addListener('places_changed', ((that) => () => this.placesChanged(that))(this));
```

Here I defined a function that takes a parameter called `that`, and upon execution returns a function that contains the this. It is a closure because the inner function's scope keeps a reference to the `that` variable from the outer functions scope (and other variables that could get passed to `this.placesChanged`).

Now if a event `places_changed` is emitted, the function declaration is ran. I am still able to change properties on the `that` variable inside the `this.placesChanged` function. This is possible because in objects are passed by reference (whereas primitive types are passed by values).